# Why is Jon Snow's hair black?

Tags: character, game-of-thrones

Many people assume Jon Snow from *Game of Thrones* is a Targaryen, but Targaryens have white hair.

Are there any other references mentioned in the book about this?

Alert if there are any spoilers.

Comment: Actually HBO [confirmed](http://www.forbes.com/sites/erikkain/2016/06/29/jon-snows-true-parentage-in-game-of-thrones-officially-confirmed-but-questions-remain/#2fc3c0d0585c) that Rhaegar is his father.

Comment: It takes 2 people to make babies.  DNA comes from both sides.  You might want to have the "talk."

Comment: Concept of DNA doesn't exist in the world of Game Of Thrones. Jon Arryn & Ned Stark didn't come to a conclusion of Cersei's incest born based on DNA test. We are talking about fantasy & fiction here. There are no silly questions. Already got the required answer from Bebs & Chanandler. Thanks to them.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The dark hair seed is stronger than the Targaryen silver hair. Remember John Aryn's last words "the seed is strong". That means that the dark hair gene is dominant.

North people tend to have dark hair, and so was Lyanna Stark.

[image: Lyanna]

That's why Jon inherited Lyanna's hair.

---

References from the books (thanks Chanandler Bong).

- [Daeron II](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Daeron_II_Targaryen) was married to [Mariah Martell](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Mariah_Martell) and his son [Baelor](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Baelor_Targaryen_(son_of_Daeron_II)) had dark hair.  <sub>The Hedge Knight</sub>
- [Rhaenys](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Rhaenys_Targaryen_(daughter_of_Rhaegar)), daughter of Rhaegar, killed during the sack of King's Landing is described with dark hair too.

Comment: Indeed, the Targaryen genes seem to be very weak, that's why they needed incest marriages to retain their dragon domination power. Also, IIRC, in _The Hedge Knight_ there was a Targaryen prince whose mother was a Dornish princess and he had dark hair. This is of course similar to [real life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_hair_color#Genetics_and_biochemistry_of_hair_color) (more or less).

Comment: Lolz, dair womens in GoT world can easily have child outside the marriage without anyone suspecting. Seed is Strong

Comment: Darn it, had my money on Robert Baratheon had had a close encounter with Lyanna Stark just before she was abducted by Rhaegar Targaryan. Making the change Eddard Stark made to Roberts will to cover Jon Snow, rather than Stannis Baratheon, if he was the oldest of the bastard sons of Robert.

Comment: You might equally ask why Robert Baratheon has dark hair. He also has Targaryen ancestry (as, of course, do his brothers), which was the basis for his claim to the throne during his rebellion.

Comment: I am pretty sure that Jon Arryn's "the seed is strong" line refers to the line of reasoning that Robert Baratheon's seed is strong, though yes, the real reason would be because of the phenotype of black hair being dominant compared to the silver-blonde phenotype of the Targaryens.

Comment: @MikeScott, I thought the basis of his claim was his warhammer...

Comment: I though that "the seed is strong" was a claim that his own son was strong and fit to inherit the Vale. Which he doesn't actually seem to be tbh. I thought it was some sort of self-delusion of a man on his deathbed.

Comment: The *seed is strong* sentence is problematic. In the most unambiguous sense, Lyanna Stark being female can only accept a seed right.

Comment: This confuses me as the "Seed is strong" is what led Jon Arryn (and Ned Stark) to figure out that the Baratheon children weren't fathered by Robert. It made sense and fit the story. While Ned was reading the book it was the fathers whose hair was a match to the offspring. Why is Jon Snow an exception? Going on the "evidence" earlier mentioned, Jon should have been a dead give away to being a Targaryen.

Comment: @TomChase, in modern terms, it says that the dark hair gene is dominant, not that the father's one is. Jon is officially Son of Eddard Start so dark hair. Unofficially the son of Lyanna so also dark hair.